# c++ do while loop issues

Tags: c++

I have the following if statement to make sure that day inputs are valid. However, if someone inputs an invalid day twice it just keeps that value. How do I make sure that the date is valid before moving on? A while loop?

```
cin>>date.day;
    if((date.day>31) || (date.month<1))
      {
          cout <<"Please input a valid day."<< endl;
          date.day = 0;
          cin>>date.day;
      }
```

Comment: Yes, I think simply changing the `if` to `while` will achieve what you want.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Did you try it? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

Using a `do` `while` structure:

```
do {
  cout <<"Please input a valid day."<< endl;
  date.day = 0;
  cin>>date.day;
  if (cin.fail()) {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
  }
} while(cin.fail() || date.day > 31 || date.day < 1);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that it's entirely possible to end up in an endless loop here if someone enters something like, "hi there!"  You probably want to be reading an entire line and then attempting to process it as an int...and THEN doing your check.  You probably also want to check the stream's viability after the operation.  if `!cin` then something bad has happened and again, your loop will just go on and on and on forever.  Read the line with getline and then parse with boost's lexical cast or a string stream.

Comment: @CrazyEddie, very good points.

Comment: @CrazyEddie Yeah, that's a good point. I haven't learned lexical casts so I'm not going to use that approach right now. Is there any other work around?

Comment: @user22507, added a suggestion to the answer

Comment: @perreal cool, but it doesn't quite work, still loops and loops.

Comment: @perreal -- are we missing cin.clear() ? That seems to solve some issue.

Comment: @user22507, yes that's a good catch.

Comment: @perreal If i input something invalid like 'ff' it prints the cout twice. Do you know why?

Comment: @user22507, updated to extend the ignore call

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a `while` loop:

```
cin>>date.day;
while((date.day>31) || (date.month<1))
{
    cout <<"Please input a valid day."<< endl;
    date.day = 0;
    cin>>date.day;
}
```